# Splitting a math expression string into tokens in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have a lot of python strings such as `"A7*4"`, `"Z3+8"`, `"B6 / 11"`, and I want to split these strings so that they would be in a list, in the format `["A7", "*", "4"]`, `["B6", "/", "11"]`, etc. I have used a lot of different split methods but I think I need to just perform the split where there is a math symbol, such as `/,*,+,-`. I would also need to strip out the whitespace.

Currently I am using the code `re.split(r'(\D)', "B6 / 11")`, which is returning `['', 'B', '6', ' ', '', '/', '', ' ', '11']`. Instead I want to get back `["B6", "/", "11"]`.

Comment: is it always just the three parts, `$operand1 $operation $operand2`?

Comment: @Pavel at this point it is just the three parts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should split on the [character set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) `[+-/*]` after removing the whitespace from the string:

```
>>> import re
>>> def mysplit(mystr):
...     return re.split("([+-/*])", mystr.replace(" ", ""))
...
>>> mysplit("A7*4")
['A7', '*', '4']
>>> mysplit("Z3+8")
['Z3', '+', '8']
>>> mysplit("B6 / 11")
['B6', '/', '11']
>>>
```

Comment: What about 6*-7?

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to solve this without regular expressions by using the Python [tokenizer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html). I used a more complex formula to show the capabilities of this solution.

```
from io import StringIO
import tokenize

formula = "(A7*4) - (Z3+8) -  ( B6 / 11)"
print([token[1] for token in tokenize.generate_tokens(StringIO(formula).readline) if token[1]])
```

Result:

```
['(', 'A7', '*', '4', ')', '-', '(', 'Z3', '+', '8', ')', '-', '(', 'B6', '/', '11', ')']
```

Comment: On python 2.7.13, the example above throws an error. `TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str` .  Need to add 'u' flag in front of formula var string.