# How to split algebraic expressions in a string using python?

Tags: python, regex

For example I get following input:

```
-9x+5x-2-4x+5
```

And I need to get following list:

```
['-9x', '5x',  '-2',  '-4x', '5']
```

Here is my code, but I  don't know  how  to  deal with minuses.

```
import re
text = '-3x-5x+2=9x-9'
text = re.split(r'\W', text)
print(text)
```

warning: I cannot use any libraries except re and math.

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042517/splitting-a-math-expression-string-into-tokens-in-python?

Comment: It is  a similiar case, but the method removes signs that are used to  split strings (for example  '-' or '+'.  I need to leave  them, but also split the text using them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could `re.findall` all groups of characters followed by `+` or `-` (or end-of-string `$`), then `strip` the `+` (which, like `-`, is still part of the following group) from the substrings.

```
>>> s = "-9x+5x-2-4x+5"
>>> [x.strip("+") for x in re.findall(r".+?(?=[+-]|$)", s)]
['-9x', '5x', '-2', '-4x', '5']
```

Similarly, for the second string with `=`, add that to the character group and also strip it off the substrings:

```
>>> s = '-3x-5x+2=9x-9'
>>> [x.strip("+=") for x in re.findall(r".+?(?=[+=-]|$)", s)]
>>> ['-3x', '-5x', '2', '9x', '-9']
```

Or apply the original comprehension to the substrings after splitting by `=`, depending on how the result should look like:

```
>>> [[x.strip("+") for x in re.findall(r".+?(?=[+-]|$)", s2)] for s2 in s.split("=")]
>>> [['-3x', '-5x', '2'], ['9x', '-9']]
```

---

In fact, now that I think of it, you can also just `findall` that match an optional minus, followed by some digits, and an optional `x`, with or without splitting by `=` first:

```
>>> [re.findall(r"-?\d+x?", s2) for s2 in s.split("=")]
[['-3x', '-5x', '2'], ['9x', '-9']]
```

Answer (score 4):

One of many possible ways:

```
import re

term = "-9x+5x-2-4x+5"

rx = re.compile(r'-?\d+[a-z]?')
factors = rx.findall(term)
print(factors)
```

This yields

```
['-9x', '5x', '-2', '-4x', '5']
```

Comment: In fact, you could also just remove the `+` from the pattern...

Comment: @tobias_k... and then use `re.findall()` altogether. You're right, thanks for spotting it.

Comment: What if you have a y in there?

Comment: @LtWorf Just replace `x?` with `[a-z]?`

Comment: @tobias_k: Though not explicitly asked for, it is very likely to have other characters than `x` as well - updated.

Answer (score 1):

For your example data, you might split on either a plus or equals sign or split when asserting a minus sign on the right which is not at the start of the string.

```
[+=]|(?=(?<!^)-)
```

- `[+=]` Match either `+` or `=`
- `|` Or
- `(?=(?<!^)-)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is `-` but not at the start of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u776hz/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/w9IZYn)

---

Output for both example strings

```
['-9x', '5x', '-2', '-4x', '5']
['-3x', '-5x', '2', '9x', '-9']
```