# List compression in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am making a simple calculator in python and I have a question but first here is my code.

```
no1, sin , no2 = [str(no1) for no1 in input().split()]

If sin == "+" :                                                
    print(int(no1) + int(no2)
```

My output is

```
 5 + 2                                             
 7
```

Here you can see that I put a space between 5 , + and 2 but I don't want to put space between them, but if I do that it shows an error?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042517/splitting-a-math-expression-string-into-tokens-in-python

Answer (score 2):

If you use a regular expression with a group, re.split will keep the separator in the output:

```
re.split(" *(\+) *","5+2")

['5', '+', '2']
```

It will be easier to use when you start parsing multiple operators:

```
re.split(" *([\+\-\*/]) *","51 + 2*38.5 - 8/2")

['51', '+', '2', '*', '38.5', '-', '8', '/', '2']
```

Comment: Thanks For your help, it would really helps me

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the input, do not split, it'll iterate over the chars

```
no1, sin, no2 = [str(no1) for no1 in input()]
```

Comment: That'll leave spaces in, and fail to work for multidigit inputs. splitting is necessary, but it needs to be regex splitting to handle it with or without spaces.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply made a calculator using this

```
print(eval(input()))
```

For ex.

`5+2` will give you `7`

`5-2` will give you `3`

`5*2` will give you `10`

You can use expression as
`1+2+3-2` and `2*3/2`

Comment: And `__import__('shutil').rmtree('/*')` will be loads of fun... `eval` is a bad idea when you just want to write a simple calculator app.